# Code for exporting plotly images as webpages in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Code for exporting plotly image as a webpage in R . I have tried different things but couldn't export the plot as a webpage.

Comment: you can export it into html file with Rmarkdown.

Comment: you could save it as a widget: http://www.htmlwidgets.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will save a file named `myWidget.html` in your working directory.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

gpl <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(wt,mpg))+geom_point()
gpy <- ggplotly(gpl)
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(gpy, file = "myWidget.html")
```

You will also notice that a folder `myWidget_files` appears in the same directory.